# Select a XML node based on priority

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML, that need to parsed using XSLT,

```
<PERSONS>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>F</TYPE>
        <NAME>ABC</NAME>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>A</TYPE>
        <NAME>XYA</NAME>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>S</TYPE>
        <NAME>AFF</NAME>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>B</TYPE>
        <NAME>HHH</NAME>
    </PERSON>
</PERSONS>
```

In the above XML, PERSON type can come in any order and i need the output as follows,

```
<SELECTED>
    <NAME>TEXT</NAME>
</SELECTED>
```

The rule is that we need to display the name based on the following priority,
A, F, S.

If type A does not exists, check for type F and display the name if exists or else display type S name.

Also it is possible that other types like B and C will come in the input XML but we need to ignore those types and only priority goes to A,F and S.

Thanks in Advance,
Wilson.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'AFS'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select="PERSON[contains($pOrder, TYPE)]">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($pOrder, TYPE))" data-type="number"/>

    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <SELECTED>
                <xsl:copy-of select="NAME"/>
            </SELECTED>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<PERSONS>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>F</TYPE>
        <NAME>ABC</NAME>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>A</TYPE>
        <NAME>XYA</NAME>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>S</TYPE>
        <NAME>AFF</NAME>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <TYPE>B</TYPE>
        <NAME>HHH</NAME>
    </PERSON>
</PERSONS>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<SELECTED>
   <NAME>XYA</NAME>
</SELECTED>
```

**If the `$pOrder` parameter is changed e.g. to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'SAF'"/>
```

**then again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<SELECTED>
   <NAME>AFF</NAME>
</SELECTED>
```

**Explanation**:

Using sort by the closeness of the string value of `Type` to the start of the ordered by priority type-strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your order appears to be alphabetical, but since you didn't say this, I'm assuming this isn't a reliable expectation.

How's this?

http://www.xmlplayground.com/cMOOBF

If indeed the order IS is reliably alphabetical, it would be better to first sort your nodes rather than use a complex predicate as I have.

Comment: I know you favour link-only answers linking to xmlplayground.com, but can you post your style-sheets explicitly? Although there is no SO policy against it, there is a tonne of discussion on the matter on the meta site, where it is almost universally consider bad practice and down-vote worthy.

Comment: Sure - I didn't realise there was any issue with this as a whole heap of JS questions I look at defer to JSFiddle sessions. Sometimes only code is required (for simple answers) but sometimes it's good to show it in action, too. Where this is the case, I'll start doing both.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `TYPE` is alphabetically sortable, you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="PERSONS">
        <xsl:for-each select="PERSON">
            <xsl:sort select="TYPE" order="ascending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <SELECTED>
                    <NAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./NAME" />
                    </NAME>
                </SELECTED>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Filburt, but sorting will not work my case bacause, it is possible to come other types also like, '<TYPE>B</TYPE>' and '<TYPE>C</TYPE>' but these things i need to ignore and only priority goes to A,F and S.

Comment: Filburt, I have included the same in the question, sorry that, i didnt mention it before.